# Let $T:R^{3}\rightarrow R^{2}$ and $K:R^{2}\rightarrow R^{3}$ a linear transformations, Prove $KT$ is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

i need help with this exercise:

> Let $T:R^{3}\rightarrow R^{2}$ and $K:R^{2}\rightarrow R^{3}$ a linear
>   transformations, Prove $KT$ is not invertible.

I know this:

By rank-nulity theorem

$Dim(R^{3})=rank(T)+nul(T)\Rightarrow3=rank(T)+nul(T)$

Then, $rank(T)\leq2$, in other words, $T$ is not inyective, and for this, $T$ is not invertible.
Also,
$KT:R^{3}\rightarrow R^{3}$

I'm stuck here, can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

$T$ is not injective implies there exist $x\neq 0$ with $T(x)=0$ this implies that $KT(x)=0$ so $KT$ is not injective, thus it is not invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Use rank-nullity on $T$ to show that $T$ has a nontrivial kernel. Then, $KT$ must have a nontrivial kernel as well, i.e. it is not injective and hence is not a bijection.

Answer (score 2):

You are close. Since $T$ is not injective, the composition cannot be injective because $T[W]=\{0\}$ for some subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (kernel), then $K[T[W]] = K[\{0\}] = \{0\}$, thus $KT$ is not injective and is not invertible.

Remember: in the finite dimensional case, the rank nullity theorem tells you injective iff surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent exercise on usage of the intuition on the Rank-Nullity theorem. Seeing as most answers are mathematically rigourous, I'll provide an intuitive argument. Consider the composition 
$$(K \circ T)(x) = K(T(x))$$
Where $T$ cannot be a bijection, as in you are squeezing a small vector space and trying to map it on a bigger vector space $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Because of this, you already know that some vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will be mapped by non-unique vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Because of this, you already know that if you apply another function (in this case, $K$) on it, it can't be a complete one-to-one correspondence (since you already "lost" some vectors while mapping $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$).

In general, multiplying many matrices together generally decreases the rank/makes it not a bijection (because the bottleneck in $ABCDEF...$ will be some matrix that forces a bigger vector space into a smaller vector space).